# Android cant tell intents apart

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, oncreate

In my main activity (where everything happens in my application) I call a variety as of now just two other activities which end up calling back to my MainActivity via button press. How do I distinguish between these two Intents back to my MainActivity? I have seperate operations I want to prefrom based on things I did back in the two seperate activites.

Heres what I tried:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String s_message = intent.getStringExtra(AppSettings.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String f_message = intent.getStringExtra(ViewFavorites.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

if(s_message != null) {
 //do something
} else if (f_message != null) {
 //do something
}
```

But when I run my application I find when exiting the two activities that they are prefroming the methods I do not wish them to...am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Set a different ACTION on each intent, then use if(getIntent().getAction().equals(ACTION)) to distinguish between intents.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String ACTION_ONE = "com.yourpackage.ACTION_ONE";
public static final String ACTION_TWO = "com.yourpackage.ACTION_TWO";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Intent intent = getIntent();
     if(intent.getAction() != null){
         if(intent.getAction.equals(ACTION_ONE){
            //DO SOMETHING
         } else if (intent.getAction.equals(ACTION_TWO){
            //DO SOMETHING
         }
     }
}
.....
```

}

Then when you start your main activity with an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MY_CURRENT_CONTEXT, MainActivity.class);  //Or MainActivity subclass
```

add

```
intent.setAction(ACTION_ONE);
```

or whichever action is specific to what your intent is trying to accomplish.

Comment: When I do this, my application crashes? IS there an immediate error I should consider or post source code

Comment: Posted some brief code to hopefully explain the concept a little better.  Not really sure why your application would be crashing without a stack trace/ your source code.

Comment: Thank you! I think it was because I was not checking if the intent's getAction was null. Its been a long week, thank you for taking the time out to help, I really appreciate it (-:

Answer (score 0):

What I do is simply set an `Extra` in my passing `Intent` then compare that. Something like this. When creating the `Intent` add an `Extra` to compare to

```
intent.putExtra("source", "appSettings");
```

then in your `Activity` check what that value is

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String source  = intent.getStringExtra("source");  // get that value here

if(s_message != null) {
    if ("appSettings".equals(source)){
    //do something
    } else if (viewFavorites.equals(source)) {
      //do something else
    }
}
```

You could use variations of this as far as how you assign the `Extra` but this is a simple example that works well for me, especially when there are just a few `Activites` that will be calling this one.